# Get thumbnail from Woocommerce Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I am using this plugin
https://woocommerce.com/products/custom-product-tag-image/
To add images to my tags.
I'd like to display a list of tags with images. I've tried so many approaches but nothing yet.

Here's my code which outputs a list of tags but no images.

```
 <?php $taxonomyName = "product_tag";
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<div class="item" > 
 <?php 
            $thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $term_img = wp_get_attachment_url(  $thumb_id ); 
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $term_img; ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

Suggestions?
```

Comment: Can you share this plugin? https://woocommerce.com/products/custom-product-tag-image/

Answer (score 1):

You can use WC `get_woocommerce_term_meta()` and WP `wp_get_attachment_url()`. check below code.

```
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
    <div class="item">
        <?php 
            $thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $term_img = wp_get_attachment_url(  $thumb_id ); 
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $term_img; ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hm. Still no dice. 
I added some code abnove the previous snippet that sets up the repeated items.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what worked for me as `woocommerce_get_term_meta` is deprecated and `thumbnail_id` doesn't exist anymore:

```
 <?php $taxonomyName = "product_tag";
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<div class="item" > 
 <?php 
            $term_image_id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'product_search_image_id', true ); 
            $term_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_image_id ); 
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $term_image; ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```